# Node.js printing back undefined for properties in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, body-parser

I'm trying to print out some data I get back after a post but it's printing as undefined. Is the parser set up correctly?

Server file

```
const taskController = require("./controllers/registration");
const express = require('express')
const parser = require('body-parser');
const app = express()
const router = express.Router();

app.use(parser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(parser.json());

app.use("/api", router);

router.route("/register").post(taskController.register);
router.route("/login").get(taskController.login);
router.route("/logout").get(taskController.logout);
var server = app.listen(3000);
```

Controller

```
var server = require('../app.js')
const mysql = require('mysql');

exports.register = function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body.fName);
  console.log(req.body.lName);
  console.log(req.body.id);
  res.send("Registering");
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try swipping `app.use(parser.urlencoded({extended:false}));` and `app.use(parser.json());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your code and run in locally. 
I do router changes 
Finally 
I make post request using curl. 
End of Answer I attach result.

Server.js

```
const taskController = require("./controllers/registration");
const express = require('express')
const parser = require('body-parser');
const app = express()
const router = express.Router();

app.use(parser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(parser.json());

app.use("/api", router);
// Here Change your router 
router.post("/register", taskController.register);

var server = app.listen(3000);
```

controllers/registration

```
exports.register = function(req, res){

    // console.log (req.body)
    console.log(req.body)

    // existing console.log
    console.log(req.body.fName);
    console.log(req.body.lName);
    console.log(req.body.id);
    res.send("Registering");
};
```

User curl to make post request 
1. without parameters

```
curl -d '{}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/register
```

// Console out put

```
{}
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

2. With parameters 
   // fName : T, lName : Black, id : 1234

   curl -d '{"fName":"T", "lName":"Black", "id" : 1234}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/register

// Console out put

```
{ fName: 'T', lName: 'Black', id: 1234 }
T
Black
1234
```

This may help you :)

Comment: Thanks! It's working with curl but not with Postman, i'll have to look into it!

Comment: May be issues with POST request Body Type 
so, 
Consider POST Request Body Type 
( form-data , x-www-form-urlencoded, row, binary )

Doc : 
https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests/
http://toolsqa.com/postman/post-request-in-postman/